# Is there a name for this use of the State design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, terminology

I'm looking to see if there is a particular name for this style of programming a certain kind of behavior into a program.

Said program runs in real time, in an update loop, and the program uses the State design pattern to do some work, but it's the specific way it does the work that I want to know about.

Here's how it's used.

```
- Object Foo constructed, with concrete StateA object in it
- First loop runs
--- Foo.Run function calls StateA.Bar
--- in StateA.Bar replace Foo's state to StateB
- Second loop runs
--- Foo.Run calls StateB.Bar
- Third loop runs
--- Foo.Run calls StateB.Bar
- Fourth loop
--- etc.
```

So in short, `Foo` doesn't have an explicit `Initialize` function. It will just have `Run`, but `Run` will do something unique in the first frame to initialize something for `Foo` and then replace it with a different action that will repeat in all the frames following it- thus not needing to check if `Foo`'s already initialized. It's just a "press start and go" action.

What would you call implementing this type of behavior?

Comment: I don't understand `in StateA.Bar replace Foo's state to StateB`.  Do you mean that the object `StateA` gets replaced by the object `StateB`?

Comment: @Robert Harvey, correct. StateA and StateB both implement the same interface and Foo stores a handle for an object using this interface.

Comment: Well, it sounds like a modified version of a Factory pattern, but a concrete implementation replacing itself with another concrete implementation seems a bit strange.

Comment: Chris is right that it's a specific use of the State pattern, but Robert is right that it's an unusual one. It seems slightly overengineered to me. Surely if you're going to do that then Foo should set the State to StateB every time, or something. Either way, it's odd enough that I doubt it has a name.

Comment: @pdr It was mostly planned to replace writing something like `if Foo.initialized, do action A, else do action B` and needing to check for that every time the loop runs. The way Foo is set up I cannot do action A anywhere but inside the loop.

Comment: In C# we would do this by passing a `delegate` to a method containing the correct action (or a lambda expression).  The amount of overhead is minimal.

Comment: @Robert Harvey good call, didn't think about that. I guess then the delegate method for action A should assign the method for action B at the end of A's method, if I want the same behavior.

Comment: @ChrisC: it sounds a bit scary to me that a child object (`StateA`) can directly modify the parent (`Foo`)'s field. Perhaps returning a `NextState` out parameter from the delegate method would have been sufficient? (or, `Foo` can perform that state change near the end of `Run` method, if its code can be modified.)

Comment: @rwong, I would agree that modifying the parent isn't the best choice, it's why I decided to go with delegates instead of state classes. Although DoFactory has a more [outlandish structural example](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternState.aspx) where two states "flip flop" constantly with each function call. Probably wasn't meant to be a real-time example though.

Answer (score 3):

I would call it [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) implemented using the [state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern):

> ...**lazy initialization** is the tactic of delaying the creation of an object, the calculation of a value, or some other expensive process until the first time it is needed.
>
> This is typically accomplished by maintaining a flag indicating whether the process has taken place. Each time the desired object is summoned, the flag is tested. If it is ready, it is returned. If not, it is initialized on the spot.
>
> See [lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) for a general treatment of this idea. In heavily imperative languages this pattern carries hidden dangers, as does any programming habit that relies on shared state...

Comment: I recall someone posted an answer saying this could be used in a video game but he deleted it. He would be right in his assumption- my actual use case is for a game, but I considered my question more of a general programming which is why it's here and not Gamedev.SE.